# Collision simplification with Box2d in a Cocos2d game

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

Consider a simple Cocos2d game consisting of five horizontal dominoes on a 1x20 grid (width is 20 squares, width of each domino is two, dominoes can't overlap). The dominoes can slide horizontally in the grid. Since they are constrained to the grid their vertical position is constant.

The logic for basic movement is simple: tapping and dragging moves a domino until `CGRectIntersectsRect` determines when another domino is hit. At this point the domino just moved snaps into place.

The logic for "advanced" movement is more complex. Here pushing a domino against another domino should move both dominoes like two consecutive train cars as long as their is room. Clearly three, four etc dominoes can be moved in this manner.

While the advanced movement code is more complex I don't think it's hopeless. I've sketched out a few concepts:

- "rear domino" is the domino user is dragging
- "front domino" is at the front of all moving dominoes and determines when to stop, when to add another domino to the group etc
- "moving dominoes" is the group of all dominoes currently in the "train"

I think this approach is doable. However I'm not convinced it's the easiest approach given the high probability of numerous corner cases. For example snapping three consecutive dominoes into place might require logic preventing overlapping after snapping, gaps after snapping etc.

**How can I avoid some of this complex logic by using Box2d?**

I think a simple physics engine completely eliminates the need for front domino, rear domino etc concepts. Hence I'm considering this approach.

Comment: Dominos should fall, right? That means they will rotate. Which means you can't use CGRectIntersect anyway because it doesn't handle rotated rectangles.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D The dominoes don't fall or rotate. They just sit in a 1x20 grid and move left/right when the user drags them.

Comment: ah, you mean those dominos with numbers on them? In that case avoid physics, it will only make things more difficult, ie moving where they shouldn't move etc

Comment: @LearnCocos2D by domino I mean just a rectangle that's one unit tall and two units wide. They don't need numbers on them. I think the physics will work. The snapping to grid might take a little extra logic.